# Java 8 stream read value from Map in List

Tags: java, java-stream

I do not want to use foreach and loop. I want to use stream in Java 8 to find value in Map inside List

```
List<Map<String, Boolean>> types = ...

map.stream().filter(...
```

problem is that in filter I can not search by key/value pair.

> I want to get all elements with boolean = true

I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Elements of all maps where **which key** is mapped to `true`?

Comment: yes all elements where boolean type = true

Comment: Yes you're doing things wrong. You have a variable called `types`, then you call `map.stream()` and we don't know where `map` came from or what it is (we know it's not a `Map` as there is no `Map.stream()`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stream over the entry set:

```
types.stream()                               // stream of maps
    .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // flat map to stream of map entries
    .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)             // filter for value == true
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)                  // get the key
    .collect(Collectors.toList());           // collect
```

You can remove `.map(Map.Entry::getKey)` if you'd rather end up with a list of key/value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<Map<String, Boolean>> types = new ArrayList<>();

    Map<String, Boolean> myMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Boolean> myMap2 = new HashMap<>();

    myMap2.put("Meric", true);
    myMap2.put("BERBER", false);
    types.add(myMap2);

    myMap.put("TEST1", true);
    myMap.put("TEST2", false);
    types.add(myMap);


    types.stream()
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .filter(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

and output will be

```
 Meric
 TEST1
```